# EF 4 does not update database record on db.SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4.1

Hi I have this code snippet below:

```
            Paypal paypal = new Paypal();
            paypal.Invoice = transactionID;
            paypal.TxnType = "";
            paypal.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
            paypal.AmountPaid = payment;

            paypal.PaymentStatusId = paymentStatus;
            db.Paypals.Add(paypal);
            db.SaveChanges();

            // Order Does not Update
            Order order = _orderRepository.GetOrderByOrderId(orderId);
            order.OrderStatusId = OrderStatusConstant.Paid;
            order.PurchasedDate = DateTime.Now;
            order.LastModified = DateTime.Now;
            order.PaypalIpnId = paypal.PaypalIpnId;
            db.SaveChanges();

            // Cart Does not Update
            Cart cart = _cartRepository.GetCartByCartId(order.CartId);
            cart.Completed = true;
            db.SaveChanges();
```

`Order` and `Cart` entity does not update. But `Paypal` object is inserted. There are no errors or any exceptions thrown this is enclosed in a `try..catch` clause.

What seems to be the problem here? Repository codes returns object fine.

Comment: You get nothing in debug mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see one thing in common here for Order and Cart and different for Paypal. Paypal is inserted using the context that is shown in the code, but Cart and Order are downloaded from the repository. Make sure that repository is using the same context.

Comment: i think kubal5003 is right. Check `object ID` of the `Context` object in the debug mode.

Comment: Hmm, they both use this context ``CHDEntities db = new CHDEntities ();``

Answer (score 1):

So... when Insert work but Update doesn't, I look at the AutoDetectChange property (in context.Configuration).

If you don't want this tracking (mean AutoDetectChange = false), you have to set manually your modified entities as modified (EntityState).

(the insert works because the Add method modifies the object's entityState)